# horizontal scrollbar in Firefox , but Chrome doesn’t show it. Anybody have any ideas how to remove that scroll from firefox?

Tags: css, angular, responsive

in my angular application facing this issue  horizontal scrollbar in Firefox , but Chrome doesn’t show it. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one solved my issue to hide vertical scroll bar from firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    html,body{overflow: hidden !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add your CSS `{overflow: hidden}`.
try this one it will help you